# Redirect user to the last page on my pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, rows

I know this sounds confusing:
I have just built some basic prev/next pagination for mysql and i wanted to know, if the last page of my rows is .php?page=5 and someone puts .php?page=263 then i want to redirect them to .php?page=5

Any ideas on how to do this.. the info i currently have is, how many rows are returned after the LIMIT so if it was .php?page=263 then it would be 0
I also have the total number of rows in my database... the LIMIT is 10 :)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the total number of rows, and you know how many rows you will be displaying per page, then you can calculate the last page like so:

```
$totalPages = ceil( $rows / $perPage );
```

Then, simply restrict the current page to a reasonable limit:

```
$page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$page = min( max( $page, 1 ), $totalPages );
```

Comment: i actually worked this out with some complicated maths just before you posted this :( haha!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is define some form of `$max_page_number` variable, then check that the page entered `$_GET['page']` is either less than the maximum possible number, or, if not, compensate for that and redirect to the last page:

$max_page_number = 10; // or whatever the maximum/last page number is,
$page_requested = $_GET['page'];

```
if ($page_requested <= $max_page_number) {

// show the page requested by the user
}

elseif ($page_requested > $max_page_number) {

// redirect to the relevant page

}

else {

// redirect to the splash page, or first page

}
```

it's also worth suggesting that you should check people can't enter `index.php?page=-10` without it being caught, so you should really check for numbers *less than* the first page and *greater than* your last page.